# X Windows special programs: do some of these still exist?

Tags: linux, x11

I recall that X11 provided a number of "fun" programs accessible via unix. For instance, if you use the command `xeyes`, an interface will pop up of cartoon-like eyes which follow your cursor everywhere.

This still works on my most update version of X11.

But I remember so many more of these fun little commands. For instance, there is:

(A) `xsnow` which causes snow to fall on your desktop, with the `santa` option

(B) `xsol` which would begin a solitaire GUI you could interact with

(C) `xmille` was something similar, and allow you to play the game Mille Borne

(D) `xroach` caused cockroaches to crawl all over your screen, with the `squish` option allow you to click/squish these buggers

(E) `xphoon` would show the moon as it appears today

(F) `xpenguins` has penguins appear

(G) `oneko` had something to do with cats and dogs

Question 1: Does anyone else still use these? The only command which still works for me is `xeyes`. Which updates do I need to use the others?

Question 2: Have I forgotten any of these types of X11 commands?

Comment: There is also `xlaby`, which shows a labyrinth and traps the mouse cursor inside, and `xbl`, which allows you to shoot holes into other windows.

Comment: The oneko cat chases the mouse, then falls asleep if the mouse didn't move.  xroachs run away from the light and hide under open windows - closing a window exposed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a debian-derivative (debian, ubuntu, linux mint), you can use the command

```
apt-cache search xmille
```

to search for any of these. Then, use

```
apt-get install xmille
```

(or the given package name). This works with `xpenguins`, too, but for example not with `oneke`. EDIT: [@dirkt points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204241/x-windows-special-programs-do-some-of-these-still-exist/204242#comment978836_204242) that it is `oneko`, which exists as a package:

```
$ apt search oneko [...]
oneko/bionic 1.2.sakura.6-13 amd64
  cat chases the cursor (now a mouse) around the screen [...]
```

Comment: That's because the name is `oneko` ("cat"), not `oneke`, and under the correct name it's still available as a Debian package.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick search on my Debian stable machine, and with the exception of `xroach` and `oneke`, they are all available with the names you gave. 
However, the correct name for `oneke` is `oneko`, and it is available in Debian with that name. What is your distribution?

Doing a little searching produces the Debian bug report
[Debian Bug report 158188: xroach: not dfsg-free](https://bugs.debian.org/158188), circa 2002, which shows Debian (in the person of illustrious Debian Developer Joey Hess) discovering that the `xroach` license was not DFSG-free, and making heroic efforts to contact the upstream author, but in vain. This bug report includes a contact attempt by our very own Anthony DeRobertis. Eventually the package was removed. It is possible you could rebuild it from sources and run it, assuming you are using a Debian derivative.

Comment: The correct names for the missing ones are `xroaches` and `oneko`

Comment: @jlliagre actually, the correct name is xroach and it used to be in Debian some years ago. You were correct about `oneko`. See edits.

Comment: My mistake for `xroaches`, `xroach` was correct indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I did some work on xsnow, xroach and xpenguins, to adapt them to modern desktops like Gnome and KDE, but also keep them working in vintage desktops like FVWM and TWM.

Xsnow and xpenguins are or will be available in Debian.

On sourceforge you find the newest versions:

xsnow: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/
xroach: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xroachng/
xpenguins: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xpenguins/

oneko is available in Debian, it runs fine in all desktops.